# How to take "MainMenuName" in below response in to nsmutablearray objective c and pass to slide menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

```
[
  {
    "MainMenuID": 1,
    "MainMenuCommonID": 0,
    "SubMenuID": null,
    "MainMenuName": "ABOUT MLA",
    "SubMenuName": null,
    "MainPageName": "ABOUTMLA",
    "LogoPath": "Images\\Icons\\about_mla.png",
    "MenuPosition": 0
  },
  {
    "MainMenuID": 2,
    "MainMenuCommonID": 0,
    "SubMenuID": null,
    "MainMenuName": "NEWS & UPDATES",
    "SubMenuName": null,
    "MainPageName": "NEWS UPDATES",
    "LogoPath": "Images\\Icons\\news.png",
    "MenuPosition": 0
  },
  {
    "MainMenuID": 3,
    "MainMenuCommonID": 0,
    "SubMenuID": null,
    "MainMenuName": "PROJECTS",
    "SubMenuName": null,
    "MainPageName": "PROJECTS",
    "LogoPath": "Images\\Icons\\projects.png",
    "MenuPosition": 0
  },
  {
    "MainMenuID": 6,
    "MainMenuCommonID": 0,
    "SubMenuID": null,
    "MainMenuName": "GRIEVANCE",
    "SubMenuName": null,
    "MainPageName": "GRIEVANCE",
    "LogoPath": "Images\\Icons\\greivance_icon.png",
    "MenuPosition": 0
  },
  {
    "MainMenuID": 8,
    "MainMenuCommonID": 0,
    "SubMenuID": null,
    "MainMenuName": "CONTACT US",
    "SubMenuName": null,
    "MainPageName": "Contact ",
    "LogoPath": "Images\\Icons\\contact.png",
    "MenuPosition": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: use `[responseObject valueForKey:@"MainMenuName"]`

Comment: can you showur tried code

Comment: Update question with the code that you have try.

Comment: So `menuList` contain this json response right?

Comment: please post the code in the Q. Nobody can read that in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like,

```
  NSArray *yourArr;   //Your array post in question
NSMutableArray *resultArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i = 0; i < yourArr.count; i++) {

    NSDictionary *tempdic = [yourArr objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *mainMenuName = [tempdic valueForKey:@"MainMenuName"];
    [resultArr addObject:mainMenuName];

}
```

`resultArr` is final result which contains `MainMenuName` from all object of `yourArr`

Comment: in  [resultArr addObject:mainMenuName];  how can i remove first object in resultArr i don't want to show first object in table cell "ABOUT MLA"  please help me on this i tried but whole data is removeing    my try     [menuList addObject:Menuname];                                                [menuList removeObjectAtIndex:0];

Comment: you can remove object like `[resultArr removeObjectAtIndex:0]` but make sure you are writing this statement outside the for loop (after for loop), If you put this inside for loop then on every iteration it's add object and remove immediately and finally your array remains empty!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use fast enumeration:

```
NSArray *yourArray;   //Your array post in question

NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *dic in yourArray) {
    [resultArray addObject:dic[@"MainMenuName"]];
}
```